# Post method not supported for this route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm getting an error on my save/store page:

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.

I have no clue as to what happened, I'm new to laravel.

Controller:
[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9diji.png)

Web route:

```php
Route::resource('post', 'PostControl');
```

Comment: It simply means that the post method is not supported for the route. Nothing that you can do about it based on my knowledge.

Comment: please add the code to your question as text not images .. also what `save` method on the controller? the `store` method?

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a POST request where it should not. See the table below:

[image]

Sending a POST to `photos.edit` route will trigger this error... for example.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things that are maybe wrong:

- your controller need to be PostController
- in laravel collective form maybe 'Action' need to be lowercase
- plural is convention for resource routes `post` => `posts`